# Changing DFS link location from command line

Tags: windows-server-2003, dfs, windows-server-2003-r2

I have the following AD DFS (Windows 2003 R2):

```
DFS Root name: members

DFS Link: me
DFS Link Target: \\myserver\meshare

DFS Link: you
DFS Link Target: \\myserver\youshare
```

I need to change all the link targets to `\\theirserver`, while keeping everything else the same. I have created the shares `meshare` and `youshare` on `\\theirserver` already, with the files they will hold.

How to accomplish this from command line (I will batch it)? Will `"dfscmd /move"` be the command to use? If so, what would the exact syntax be?

Comment: It would be helpful to know whether you are running Windows Server 2003, or Server 2003 R2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper command is:

```
dfscmd /unmap "\\domain\members\me"
dfscmd /unmap "\\domain\members\you"
```

and then:

```
dfscmd /map "\\domain\members\me" "\\theirserver\meshare"
dfscmd /map "\\domain\members\you" "\\theirserver\youshare"
```

Too bad it there isn't a command that does both, in one shot.

Answer (score 1):

For Server 2003 R2, try:

```
DFScmd /remove \\Domain\members\me \\myserver\meshare
DFScmd /remove \\Domain\members\you \\myserver\youshare
```

and then

```
DFScmd /add \\Domain\members\me \\theirserver\meshare
DFScmd /add \\Domain\members\you \\theirserver\youshare
```

For Server 2008, you could use the following commands:

```
dfsutil target remove \\domain\members\me \\myserver\meshare
dfsutil target remove \\domain\members\you \\myserver\youshare
```

and then

```
dfsutil target add \\domain\members\me \\theirserver\meshare
dfsutil target add \\domain\members\you \\theirserver\youshare
```

Comment: There are not such options for dfsutil. At least, not on Windows 2003 R2.

Comment: I've updated my answer with alternate (older) commands, leaving the Server 2008 commands for reference. I've only got Server 2008 at my disposal, so I can't test the DFScmd.

Comment: The "/remove" option removes a replica from a DFS volume. I am not trying to do that. I want to either replace an existing target's link target, or remove specifics links, and re-add them with a different link target.